# Flutter TextFormField with dynamic suffixIcon

Tags: flutter

The objective is to show/hide a suffixIcon that clears out the field on a Flutter TextFormField. It should only be visible if there is text in the box.

The field looks like this:

```
TextFormField(                  
  controller: _usernameController,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: 'Username',
    suffixIcon: usernameNotEmpty == true ? IconButton(
      onPressed: () {
        _usernameController.clear();
      },
      icon: Icon(Icons.cancel, color: Colors.grey)
    ) : null
  ),                  
)
```

and the event listener looks like this:

```
var usernameNotEmpty;
_usernameController.addListener(() {
   usernameNotEmpty = _usernameController.text.length > 0 ? true : false; 
   print(_usernameController.text);
});
```

So the realtime updated text does appear in the console. But the `suffixIcon` is never shown.  Since the TextFormField doesn't have an `onChange` event, how can this `suffixIcon` be shown/hidden?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cleaned up and working:

```
_usernameController.addListener(() {
  setState(() {}); 
});

TextFormField(                  
  controller: _usernameController,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: 'Username',
    suffixIcon: _usernameController.text.length > 0 ? IconButton(
      onPressed: () {
        _usernameController.clear();
      },
      icon: Icon(Icons.cancel, color: Colors.grey)
    ) : null
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use **suffix**, not suffixIcon. Suffix widget behaves as you expected. it will be shown if TextField is not empty.

```
TextFormField(                  
  controller: _usernameController,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: 'Username',
    suffix: IconButton(
      onPressed: () {
        _usernameController.clear();
      },
      icon: Icon(Icons.cancel, color: Colors.grey)
    )
  ),
```